# Suppose 3 houses have 12 people each and 1 house has 3 people. How many 4 people combination can I make, each time taking 1 person per house?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose 3 houses have 12 people each and 1 house has 3 people. How many 4 people combination can I make, each time taking 1 person per house? How will the answer change if I add the condition of  "taking 1 person from each house without replacement"?

Comment: **Hint:**  How many ways can you choose a person from each house?  Apply the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather strange question. Using the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) there are $12^4 \cdot 3 = 62208$ ways of choosing four people, one per house. Adding the condition of ‘without replacement’ would only make a difference if we could choose more than one person from the same house, which we can’t—so the result is the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer.